# paypal item sold confirmation through APIs

Tags: paypal, api

I sold an item on my website. The item belong to another customer, who used my website to sell his stuff. How can I get solid confirmation from Paypal through API so that I can send the seller an email that he should ship hi item as the amount has been paid.

I am using paypal free version transactions take place at PayPal.com (and it works for me). I do have a confirmation page where buyer is returned after he pays for the time but I want something solid. What if he does not return to confirmation page? What if he comes to confirmation page twice?

Comment: The link back to the confirmation page _should_ contain the transaction ID.  If you see the same ID twice, that means the customer has reloaded the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal's online documentation seems pretty confusing (with some seemingly official pages saying one thing and others saying the opposite), but I think what you may want is their [Instant Payment Notification](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) feature.  If the page I linked to is to be believed, this lets PayPal notify you about completed payments and other events through a script on your website, without requiring the customer to return to your site after paying.

Alternatively, you might want to see if perhaps PayPal's [e-mail notification](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons#id089UI0T50NW)  feature might be enough for your needs.

Comment: I read about it a while ago. I will look into it again and select accepted answer once I implement it.